# Turn off All HTML5 Video

Tags: html5-video

I'm looking for a method to turn off all HTML5 video on a site with a single video. I'm developing an app that uses modal windows to show content. Some of this content is HTML5 video. When a user plays a video and then decides to close the modal window containing that video, I would like the video to stop.

I've tried a method like the following:

```
function stopVideo() {
    // Make sure to turn off and reset the video
    $( '.html5-video' ).each( function( index, element ) {
        $( this ).get( 0 ).currentTime = 0;
        $( this ).get( 0 ).pause();
    } );
}
```

This works fine in Safari; however, in FireFox and Chrome, it throws an error suggesting that because the element is hidden, it is no longer useable. Does anyone have an idea of how to reliably stop all video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's something you should learn about jQuery.
Everytime you call $() (with some arguments) a new jQuery object is created, which is bad for performance. If you do the a call to $() with the same arguments, you should cache the result, so in your case this would be:

```
var video_object = $(this).get(0);
video_object.currentTime = 0;
video_object.pause();
```

Secondly, when you an each-loop with jQuery, the context in your function (this) and the second argument are html-objects. So wrapping them in a $()-method and then doing a .get(0) makes no sense.

So this is the same as your method:

```
function stopVideo() {
    // Make sure to turn off and reset the video
    $( '.html5-video' ).each( function( index, element ) {
      element.currentTime = 0;
      element.pause();
    } );
}
```

Back to your problem now.
Can you give an example, or some more details, because the code above seems to be working without errors for me (http://jsfiddle.net/klaascuvelier/fypAR/)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I do need to do some optimization here for sure. Before I throw up an example, can you see if it works in Firefox and Chrome? It works fine for me in Safari. Additionally, the issue seems to be that the HTML5 video elements are wrapped in a hidden element and hence the reason the I get the error.

Comment: I realized the previous comment made it sound like I haven't checked it in FF or Chrome. I have and that is where the error occurs. It doesn't happen in Safari.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle link in my previous post, thats what I tried in Chrome & Firefox, both work for me.